# Most mutually distant k elements (clustering?)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, combinations, k-means

I have a simple machine learning question:

I have n (~110) elements, and a matrix of all the pairwise distances. I would like to choose the 10 elements that are most far apart. That is, I want to

```
Maximize:
  Choose 10 different elements.
  Return min distance over (all pairings within the 10).
```

My distance metric is symmetric and respects the triangle inequality.

What kind of algorithm can I use? My first instinct is to do the following:

1. Cluster the n elements into 20
   clusters.
2. Replace each cluster with just the
   element of that cluster that is
   furthest from the mean element of
   the original n.
3. Use brute force to solve the
   problem on the remaining 20
   candidates. Luckily, 20 choose 10 is
   only 184,756.

---

Edit: thanks to etarion's insightful comment, changed "Return sum of (distances)" to "Return min distance" in the optimization problem statement.

Comment: IF the points are in 3d .. 8d, first find the convex hull -- see e.g. [qhull](http://www.qhull.org) up to 8d -- and exclude all the points inside the hull, for a good reduction in problem size. (Proof ?)

Comment: What is the application? Reason for the question is, I feel like the "sum of distances" is not very close to "most far apart". I'd expect something like "Return minimum distance over all pairs" in the last line to get something that resemples "most far apart".

Comment: @Denis great suggestion! But don't you mean find the "concave hull"  and exclude the points inside? (Convex hull = contracting rubber band, and by defn includes all points. Concave hull = expanding balloon, minimum-bounding the perimeter.) Applying the concave hull idea here will look like carlosdc's greedy algorithm: 100x, remove the point most similar to all remaining.

Comment: @etarion Excellent observation, and your intuition is correct for my application. This is for a Synthetic Biology project: the 110 elements are 110 interchangeable DNA sequences that all act as "promoters" (see Wikipedia). In a complex genetic circuit, one needs to use about 10 different promoters. The trick is to choose a set of promoters that have the min possible DNA sequence homology. Homology is bad because homologous sequences tend to spontaneous connect ("recombine") to each other, splicing out the intervening DNA, and thus ruining your genetic system.

Comment: I think we mean the same thing; convex is the usual term. [Convex hull algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) lists O( n log h ) algorithms, with h << n points on the hull / outside / boundary. n ~ 100 is small though, O(n^2) fast enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you might approach this combinatorial optimization problem by taking the convex relaxation.

Let D be an upper triangular matrix with your distances on the upper triangle. I.e. where i < j, D_i,j is the distance between elements i and j. (Presumably, you'll have zeros on the diagonal, as well.)

Then your objective is to maximize x'*D*x, where x is binary valued with 10 elements set to 1 and the rest to 0. (Setting the ith entry in x to 1 is analogous to selecting the ith element as one of your 10 elements.)

The "standard" convex optimization thing to do with a combinatorial problem like this is to relax the constraints such that x need not be discrete valued. Doing so gives us the following problem:

maximize y'*D*y
subject to: 0 <= y_i <= 1 for all i, 1'*y = 10

This is (morally) a quadratic program. (If we replace D with D + D', it'll become a bona fide quadratic program and the y you get out should be no different.) You can use an off-the-shelf QP solver, or just plug it in to the convex optimization solver of your choice (e.g. cvx).

The y you get out need not be (and probably won't be) a binary vector, but you can convert the scalar values to discrete ones in a bunch of ways. (The simplest is probably to let x be 1 in the 10 entries where y_i is highest, but you might need to do something a little more complicated.) In any case, y'*D*y with the y you get out does give you an upper bound for the optimal value of x'*D*x, so if the x you construct from y has x'*D*x very close to y'*D*y, you can be pretty happy with your approximation.

Let me know if any of this is unclear, notation or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question.

I'm not sure if it can be solved exactly in an efficient manner, and your clustering based solution seems reasonable. Another direction to look at would be local search method such as simulated annealing and hill climbing.

Here's an obvious baseline I would compare any other solution against:

1. Repeat 100 times:
2. Greedily select the datapoint that whose removal decreases the objective function the least and remove it.

Comment: +1 Good suggestions, thanks! I'll wait a little while for diverse answers before accepting one.