# Find m most distant points from a set of n points

Tags: optimization, graph

I would like to find the m maximally distant subset of points from a collection of n d-dimensional points.

Note: I found a similar question on this topic, but unfortunately the proposed answer requires convex optimization (QP) which is not suitable for the very large number of points that I require (n).

[Most mutually distant k elements (clustering?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400905/most-mutually-distant-k-elements-clustering)

I have tried the following algorithm

- Add the n d-dimensional points to a kd-tree
- while subset S size is greater than n

  - find the point q from the kd-tree that is least distant to any of its neighbors
  - remove point q from the kd-tree and the subset S

return the subset S of m maximally distant points

This is obviously non-deterministic since the order in which the points are removed affects the eventual subset of S (this however occasionally returns the correct solution). But the complexity is (n - m)log(n) which is favorable considering n will be > 100,000.

Does anyone have ideas about how to improve/replace the above algorithms whilst keeping the complexity down?

Comment: You may consider submit to mathoverflow

Comment: @JulienS. I did not know about this site but I might flip my question to there, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a hilbert curve and presort the points along a curve, for example in cgal and triangulation it is used.

Comment: This was a very interesting suggestion.  I implemented this for 3-d but unfortunately this does not give a solution that I can work with.  This results in the point set being distributed along the Hilbert Curve. In the case of the input 3-d points lying on a sphere for example, the first sorted point would be coincident with the last sorted point.  Where as what I really want is the first point be maximally distant from the last.  Very interesting stuff though!

Comment: @difftator:Are you absolutely sure? You can translate the points to a binary and interleave it. I think you must done something wrong. Only in the moore curve the curve ends near the start.

Comment: I will take another look at the implementation - I also need to find some reasonable test cases as a reality check.